# Javascript click gets always the first item from multiple items with similar class

Tags: javascript, css

I am a beginner in JavaScript.
I have five (05) html divs like this:

```
                                <div class="ddmenu">
                                    <a href="#"><i class="fa fas fa-cog"></i>Items<i
                                        class="fa fa-chevron-right rotate float-end"> </i> </a>
                                    <ul class="sub-links">
                                        <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
```

And a css to rotate the fa-chevron-right like this:

```
.down{
    -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

Handled by below JavaScript:

```
var mainparentelements = document.querySelectorAll('.ddmenu');
for (let i = 0; i < mainparentelements.length; i++) {
    mainparentelements[i].onclick = function() {
    var toberotated = document.querySelector('.fa-chevron-right');
    toberotated.classList.add("down");  
    };
}
```

Now the problem is: no matter which main item I click, its always the fist `fa-chevron-right` which gets rotated (of course). How can I bind the rotation action and class to each individual rather to just one? What I am missing here? Feeling clueless. Any reading or directions or solution will be greatly appreciated. Looking for kind help using css and pure vanilla Javascript only.

Comment: `document.querySelector('.fa-chevron-right')` - this will always get the first one. That's how `querySelector` works. One way to solve the problem is to use `event.target.querySelector(...)`

Comment: Yeah I mentioned - of course :-)

Comment: Suggestion: instead of using multiple event listeners, consider adding a single click event listener on the parent element of all `.ddmenu` elements and take advantage of [event bubbling](https://javascript.info/bubbling-and-capturing)

Comment: [Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/GnLlYV36x53SaA3F?open=lib%2Fscript.js) that takes advantage of [event bubbling](https://javascript.info/bubbling-and-capturing).

Comment: The demo works exactly as I wanted Yousaf. Can you please put it as an answer. I will accept that. Thanks a ton.!

Comment: Don't worry about that, you needed help and you have been helped :) You should accept the answer that is already present. It answers your original question which didn't include the requirement that there should be only one icon with the class of "down".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reference the parent element you're iterating over inside the loop instead of using `querySelector`, and you can get from the clicked parent element to the `.fa` descendant:

```
mainparentelements[i].onclick = function () {
  var toberotated = mainparentelements[i].querySelector('.fa-chevron-right');
  toberotated.classList.add("down");
};
```

You can also make the code a lot more concise by invoking the iterator instead:

```
for (const parent of document.querySelectorAll('.ddmenu')) {
  parent.onclick = () => {
    parent.querySelector('.fa-chevron-right').classList.add("down");
  };
}
```

Comment: hmmm that does the trick but now the icon remains rotated even if I click other parent. Please suggest how can I overcome that? I mean how can I rotate it back once I jump to other sibling (parent)?

Comment: You can save the toggled element in an outer variable if you want, or you can do `document.querySelector('.down')?.classList.remove('down')`, or something like that